# Javascript code that can capture screenshot of a website

Tags: javascript, html, screenshot

I have got a javascript code that can capture a website's screenshot. But i don't know how to  call that javascript using html. Can anyone please help me. Given below are the links and the code

Demo: http://ctrlq.org/screenshots/
Documentation: http://ctrlq.org/code/19136-screenshots-javascript

Code:

```
var system = require('system');

// Web Address (URL) of the page to capture
var url  = system.args[1];

// File name of the captured image
var file = system.args[2]  + ".png";

var page = require('webpage').create();

// Browser size - height and width in pixels
// Change the viewport to 480x320 to emulate the iPhone
page.viewportSize = { width: 1200, height : 800 };

// Set the User Agent String 
// You can change it to iPad or Android for mobile screenshots
page.settings.userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5";

// Render the screenshot image
page.open ( url, function ( status ) {
  if ( status !== "success") {
       console.log("Could not open web page : " + url);
       phantom.exit();
   } else {
       window.setTimeout ( function() {
          page.render(file);
          console.log("Download the screenshot : " + file);
          phantom.exit();
       }, 1000);
   }
});
```

Comment: You cannot. It's not a client side JS

Comment: That's Node.js code.  You cannot do this in a browser.

Comment: @zerkms then how can i make it work??

Comment: @SLaks then how can i make it work??

Comment: @user3392772: your question makes no sense. "This wheel is not for a bicycle but for a car" "- But how to use it with a bicycle?" --- is this analogy clear for you?

Comment: @zerkms Ok. Got it. Is there any way that i can capture screenshot of a given website??

Comment: @user3392772: in js in a browser - nope.

Comment: @zerkms is it possible in server?

Comment: @user3392772: what do you think the code you've provided is doing?